# What operation corresponds to spatial derivatives on smooth vector fields, if any?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\pi:E\to M$ be a smooth vector bundle on a $d$ dimensional manifold.

By choosing some local coordinates $x^\mu=x^\mu(p)=(x_1(p),\ldots,x_d(p))$ on a chart $U$ and some section $v:M\to E$, every $v(p)\in \pi^{-1}(\{p\})=V_p$ can be described locally by $v(x^\mu(p))$ if I'm not mistaken.

My question is wether we are allowed to do

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac1h(v{(x_1,\ldots,x_i+h,\ldots,x_d)}-v{(x_1,\ldots,x_i,\ldots,x_d)})\right).$$

If $V$ is the vector field on $U$ defined by the restriction of the section $v$ on $U$, what operation does it define? Is it $\dfrac{\partial v({x^\mu})}{\partial x^i}$, $(\nabla_i V)_p$ or something else?

My guess would be that we can parallel transport $v(p)$ from $x^\mu$ to $x^{\mu+h}=(x_1,\ldots,x_i+h,\ldots,x_d)$ and then take the usual derivative on $V_{x^{\mu+h}}$, so I think that it is well defined. The problem is I don't know what operation it is equivalent to. Any light would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

Couldn't we just define $v(x+h)=L_h(v(x))$ where $L_h\circ L_{h'}=L_{h+h'}$ linear iso and take the derivative of $L$ at $0$ giving us that the result is the connection applied to $v(p)$? Isn't parallel transport defined this way giving us a sense of defining the above?

Comment: What do you mean by substraction above ?

Comment: @Eumenes I don't really know cause I know that there is no canonical way to add vectors in different vector spaces, but we take the limit $h\to 0$ and _maybe_ there is a way to make sense of it, hence the question.

Comment: If you move it using parallel transport then you have $(\nabla_i v)_p$.

Comment: The way you define it you will get the partial derivative $\partial v^j/\partial x^j$. The issue with this is that it's not tensorial (i.e. it depends on the chart). If you want something tensorial, you have to put a connection on the vector bundle.

Comment: @Eumenes Does that mean that the edit works for it to be $(\nabla_i v)_p$ as long as we have some $L$ defining the connection? I'm sorry but I really need a clear answer for this.

Comment: What is $L_h$ ?

Comment: @Eumenes If $L_p^q:\pi^{-1}(\{p\})\to\pi^{-1}(\{q\})$ linear iso where $L_p^q(v(p))=v(q)$ then $L_h:=L_{x^\mu}^{x^\mu+h}$ locally. So $v(x+h)-v(x)=L_h(v(x))-L_0(v(x))=(L_h-L_0)(v(x))$.

Comment: The problem is that $v(x+h) -v(x)$ has no meaning since both are in different tangent spaces.

Comment: @Eumenes I think I understand now. So I need to take the difference between the section at $x$ and the section at $x+h$ _parallel transported_ to $x$. Meaning instead of $v(x+h)$ I should write $v'(x)=L_{-h}(v(x+h))$, am I right?

Comment: Yes. But then the answer will depends on your set of isomorphisms also. But if you choose the isomorphisms as parallel transport operator $\Gamma$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport) then the limit is coincide with $\nabla$.

Comment: @Eumenes Yes that's what I meant, so the section may not be "invariant" under $L$, which, if it is, it is parallel transported and has $0$ covariant derivative. Thank you very much. This really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a choice of coordinates, you *can* take a derivative of a vector field in this manner, but the result will depend on your choice of coordinates. If, however, you want to take such a derivative in a *coordinate independent* manner, it isn't really possible to define such a derivative canonically.

The problem is that "subtracting" vectors in different fibers has no intrinsic meaning, and defining things in coordinates as you do will not be consistent. This is precisely what a connection is: an additional piece of data which makes these kind of derivatives unambiguous. This extra data is generally necessary.

For a vector bundle $\pi:E\to M$, a common starting point is to define an operator $\nabla:\Gamma(TM)\times\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)$ (satisfying a product rule) as this additional piece of data, and define this to be the derivative for vector fields. In general, a given vector bundle can have many different connections.

By choosing a coordinate chart and defining a derivative as you do, you are essentially defining a (local, flat) connection such that fields with constant coordinates in that chart have vanishing derivative.